# has_many through join table attributes not accessible

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have the following models:

```
User
--------
has_many :publications, through: :publication_users

Publication
--------
has_many :users, through: :publication_users

PublicationUser
--------
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :publication
```

I want to be able to call `Publication.first.users.first.role` but I'm getting `undefined method 'role' for #<User:0x007fc03f0ff080>` as an error. How can I access this relational attribute?

I also want to be able to set the role of each user. For example:

```
def make_creator_admin
    # have some way of setting the role here. Right now I can't :(
    self.users << self.owner
end
```

All I've managed to find is a bunch of posts about `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but that appears to be more specific to form submissions. Any ideas how to manage this effectively?

To summarize, I want to be able to accomplish the two following items:

**1. Access the role of a user associated with a publication**

**2. Set the role for that user**

Comment: What is a "role" in this scenario? An attribute on the User model? A persisted object?

Comment: it's an attribute in the join table `publication_users`

Comment: An attribute in the join table?

Comment: How are you using the `make_creator_admin` method? is it an `after_save`? and where?

Answer (score 0):

If `role` is an attribute on the `publication_users` table, why call `Publication.first.users.first.role`? Why not `Publication.first.publication_users.first.role`

Include an `has_many :publication_users` to both your models:

```
#User Model
--------
has_many :publication_users
has_many :publications, through: :publication_users

#Publication Model
--------
has_many :publication_users
has_many :users, through: :publication_users
```

Also, to set the role for a user in an association, target the association, not the user, just like the above

Comment: I already have that ... it doesn't make the attribute accessible though. You need to do a completely separate query apparently. The unfortunate solution that I went with was: `PublicationUser.where(:user_id => self.owner.id, :publication_id => self.id).update_all(:role => 'admin')`